# activeClassName on Nav link not working - react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

Trying to change the style of Nav link in the navbar when clicked , i understood from a google search that i should use "activeClassName". Tried using it and it's not working. What i'm doing wrong?

The menu code:

```
    <Navbar bg="none" expand="md">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">Bloom</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ml-auto order-0">
          <Nav.Link activeClassName="active" href="/contact">main</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link activeClassName="active" href="/about">main</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link activeClassName="active" href="/guide">main</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link activeClassName="active" href="/brands">main</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link activeClassName="active" href="/" exact>
            main
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

The styling:

```
   .active{
 color:red;
}
```

I try keeping my code simple as possible so if you have a better way would love to hear.

Comment: are you using react-bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing it with the [react router's `NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) element.

Your code seems to be using the react-bootstrap `Nav.Link` element.

You should use the `activeKey` prop on the parent `Nav` element to mark the active one.

```
<Nav className="ml-auto order-0" activeKey="/contact">
  <Nav.Link href="/contact">main</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="/about">main</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="/guide">main</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="/brands">main</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="/" exact>
    main
  </Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

This will automatically add an `active` class to the active link.

Comment: Yes it got me confused. What is the simplest way to change the style when menu item is chosen? I found that i can use onSelect to call a function but maybe do you know a better way? Thank you!